# Neighborhood data for Canada

Tags: data, canada

I am looking for Canada Locality/neighborhood data but did not get any useful links. Anybody know about a good Locality/neighborhood data for Canada??

Comment: You may want to try asking over at https://opendata.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank you. I would do that. that seems more appropriate platform.

Comment: https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/12599/6229

Comment: Where exactly? Across the whole country? Some cities like Toronto have great open data portals that might have what you're looking for, for the city in question.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you need it for, the Canadian government has a wealth of open data available: https://www.nrcan.gc.ca/earth-sciences/geography/topographic-information/free-data-geogratis/11042

Comment: Yeah, they have good data for almost everything but I don't see any neighborhood data on that site.